# Settings for vase mode in Cura?

Tags: ultimaker-cura, software

I keep hearing about vase mode, but I have some problem figuring out how to set it up in my slicer; I use Cura slicer.

So, I'd like to get some settings to do it in Ultimaker Cura, using PLA if the material is important, plus any advice on how to properly do it and ensure that the print retains it's shape on print.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Vase Mode changed the name in some version before 3.5. Now you can achieve this with 2 modes: "Surface Mode" and "Spiralize Outer Contour". To turn it on do this:

- Choose the Custom setting menu on the right
- click a gear to set up what settings you want to see
- Under the header "Special Modes" you find both Surface Mode and Spiralize Outer Contour
- set the checkmarks on both

Turning on the Surface mode to `Surface` and checking `Spiralize Outer Contour` gets the "classic" Vase Mode.

Turning on `Surface` without `Spiralize Outer Contour` gets an infill-less outer perimeter

Now, the *classic* Vase mode will only print the *single most outer perimeter* of a print, so your model will have to be very limited with angles and contain no bridges - with one perimeter, you will only be able to print at best 45° angles!

Comment: I would add to this answer that you'll probably want to change the thickness of the bottom (e.g. change "Bottom Layers" from 6 to 2), otherwise your vase will have a really thick base even though the sides are only a single layer thick, which probably isn't what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Option `Spiralize` makes your model one layer thick on outer edges.

What I do for a vase is set the top layer count to zero.